# CMD script - copy files with name end _0001.png

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

I need help writing a script in cmd

I am in a folder that has subfolders in it, you have to search these subfolders (do not go deeper) and copy files whose name ends with "_0001.png" to the folder !! _ TEMP (this folder is in the place where the program starts)

Can you help me?

This not work:

```
for /R "%folder%" %%G in (*_0001.png) do copy "%%G" "%folder%\!!_TEMP\"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pushd "%folder%"
for /D %%D in (*) do copy "%%D\*_0001.png" "!!_TEMP"
popd
```

Answer (score 1):

CMD is not my strength, so I'll offer my Powershell solution.

```
$content = Get-ChildItem .\Desktop\localtmp -Depth 1
foreach($file in $content){
    if($file.Name -like "*_0001.png"){
    $path = $file.DirectoryName + "\" + $file.Name
        Copy-Item $path -Destination .\Desktop\anotherlocaltmp
    }
}
```

you just need to add your paths

Hope it helps!

Comment: thx but i create .bat file so this not work for me :(

Comment: if that task is the only job of the script, take mine put it as a .ps1 and sit back and relax ^^
or is it larger?

Comment: unfortunately a lot larger :( 
but thank you anyway

Comment: I'm sorry i couldn't help you further, if you have any problems with Powershell feel free to come back at me ;)
Good luck!

Comment: @Alan if you really need to call it from a batch file then use `powershell -command your_command` or `powershell -file scriptfile`. But if you're new to cmd then do yourself a favor and learn powershell instead. It's much more powerful and doesn't contain legacy issues

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
@echo off

set "dir=C:\Your\Root\Folder"
set "tem=%dir%\!!_Temp"

for /d %%A in (*) do (
    for %%B in (%%A\*_0001.png) do (
        if not exist "%tem%\%%~nxB" copy /y "%%B" "%tem%\" 
    )
)
```

To make things cleaner and easier to change, we set two variables - one for your root folder (`dir`) and one for the `!!_Temp` folder (`tem`) inside your root; this also assumes based on your question that you're running the .bat file from the root folder - if this isn't the case we can edit the path in the first for-loop.

The first loop has `for /d` which looks only at top-level folders in your current directory, and for each iteration of the loop those top-level folders are set as parameter `%%A`. The next loop looks only at files matching the criteria we set - which is anything in `%%A` that ends in `_0001.png` - and sets each of those as parameter `%%B`. The command in this final loop is `if not exist "%tem%\%%~nxB" copy /y "%%B" "%tem%\"` - we include the `if not exist` so it doesn't run on files that have already been copied to `!!_Temp`. Based on your question I'm not sure if you'd ever run into multiple files in multiple subfolders that have the exact same name, but if that is a potential case we can work around that.

Answer (score 0):

This one line for loop should work.
It has the same variables as the ones you are using.

```
for /f "delims==" %%G in ('dir "%folder%\*_0001.png" /s /b') do copy "%%G" "%folder%\!!_TEMP\"
```